# iOS Tester Only Features

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, testing

I am trying to point my app at the production server for final and beta (TestFlight) testers but for alpha testers I want them to to get an extra little button.

My target is set up to have Build and Release variables and those are working fine:

```
//:configuration = Debug
BASE_URL = https://debug.myserver.com

//:configuration = Release
BASE_URL = https://release.myserver.com
```

And then I can just enable disable the button (Swift 3) :

```
#if DEBUG
    // We can leave the button
    ChangeServerButton.isEnabled = true
#else
    ....etc
```

So far though, the only time I see my button is when I use XCode (8.1) to run directly on my phone.  The process of "Archiving" seems to only create release software.

Surely I am just missing something obvious here.  Would anyone care to jump in?

Comment: Sorry.. to be clear I realize that my BASE_URL definition is only tangentially related to the '#if DEBUG' below it.     I do need the debug value for base url though in the debug mode.   I guess I'm just not really building debug builds

Comment: You can select what build configuration you want it to use when archiving in the scheme editor.

Comment: @dan That has done the trick and I presume normal use is to create a new scheme for development and use that primarily until you are very close.   Thanks!  And would like to phrase your comment in the form of an answer ?